# How can the highlighting of a vertical tab when it's clicked be prevented?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css

I have these tabs:

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={currentMenuItem}>
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>     
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.authentication} name="auth">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.dataMapping} name="dataMapping">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.pageLayouts} name="pageLayouts">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

They look like this:

[image]

The requirement is for navigation only to be possible by "back" and "next" buttons at the bottom of the component, with next only allowed when work is completed on the current tab.

`onselect` on `<lightning-vertical-navigation>` is not set. Regardless, the tabs are highlighted when clicked.

Is there a way to prevent highlighting the tabs when they're clicked?

I tried setting `selected-item` on `<lightning-vertical-navigation>` back to the desired tab with `onselect`, but that does nothing.

Is there some css override I can do (I'm weak in styling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lightning-vertical-navigation` has a `beforeselect` event and you can use its handler to prevent the click's default:

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation
    selected-item={currentMenuItem}
    onbeforeselect={handleBeforeTabSelection}
>
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>     
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.authentication} name="auth">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.dataMapping} name="dataMapping">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.pageLayouts} name="pageLayouts">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

Function:

```
handleBeforeTabSelection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using `pointer-events` property in CSS:

HTML:

```html
<lightning-vertical-navigation class="no-pointer-events">
```

CSS:

```css
.no-pointer-events{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

By this way, any click event on the navigation item can be avoided. In addition to that, active tab will also get highlighted when navigating through Next/Back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS class to your component to target the active/selected tab. Let's call it **no-highlight**.

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={currentMenuItem}>
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.authentication} name="auth" onclick={handleTabClick}>
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.dataMapping} name="dataMapping" onclick={handleTabClick}>
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label={labels.pageLayouts} name="pageLayouts" onclick={handleTabClick}>
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

In your JS controller or helper, define the handleTabClick function to handle the click event:

```
handleTabClick(event) {
    const tabItems = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelectorAll('lightning-vertical-navigation-item');
    tabItems.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove('no-highlight');
    });
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('no-highlight');
}
```

Apply **CSS pointer-events property** to remove the highlight effect for the selected tab:

```
.no-highlight {
    **pointer-events: none;**
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Hope this Helps !